# Function printing in Print Function in Python

Tags: python, function

My question is for below code why None is getting print in place of function output and why function output is getting before its position.

```
def print_spam():
    print('spam')


def do_twice(r,ps):
    g  = ps()
    print(r,'is a',g)
    print(r,'is a',ps())

do_twice('xyz',print_spam)
```

Output is

```
spam
xyz is a None
spam
xyz is a None
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function `print_spam()` does not `return` anything. It just `print`s a statement.

Change it to:

```
def print_spam():
    print('spam')
    return 'spam'
```

Because your function doesn't return anything, it defaults to `None`. Now when assigning the function output to `g`, it will contain the returned string of the function (`spam`).

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing

```
g  = ps() 
print(r,'is a',g)
```

with

```
g  = ps 
print r,'is a', 
g()
```

anyway, as pointed out by some other answers, print_spam() returns None